# Config an application page as public in keycloak

Tags: authentication, angular7, keycloak, keycloak-services

I was recently working on keycloak authentication. My Whole application is secured using keycloak. Now I got a scenario that some of the pages of keycloak must be public i.e. that public pages must be accessible without login.
For Example My Application URL is **http://HOST:PORT/** if i setup keycloak for that then each and every single page has to be accessible via  login from Keycloak.

I want **http://HOST:PORT/aboutus** or **http://HOST:PORT/contactus** must be marked as public .

These kind of pages must be accessible directly by the user . User don't have to login for these pages.

Is there any way in keycloak to get this Solution?

Please help in this.

Thanks in advance

```
Shashi Bhushan
Happy Coding :)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `keycloak-gatekeeper` then just define whitelisted resources:

```
resources:
- uri: /*
- uri: /contactus 
  white-listed: true
- uri: /aboutus 
  white-listed: true
```

Comment: i am new in keycloak, can please explain how i integrate "keycloak-gatekeeper" in my existing keycloak server.

Comment: @SHASHIBHUSHAN why did you add tag 'keycloak-gatekeeper', when you are not using it? Wrong question -> wrong answer.